# Dialog outside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a little problem with a JavaScript dialog.
I have a button and a dialog into the iframe with the next code

```
$( "#correcto" ).dialog({
    width: 600,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 200
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 200
  }
});
```

And the button with this code:

```
$( "#comprobar" ).click(function() {
      $( "#correcto" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

The code works, but open the dialog into the iframe and the overlay and modal only show/work into the iframe and looks really weird.

I want to know if there are some code to open the dialog outside the iframe. I found another thread with a similar question and I try to initialize the dialog in the main page (the parent) and use **parent.** in the button code but it doesn't work.

Comment: `w=window.open(...);w.document.write(dialogHTML);` ?

Comment: sry @vp_arth, but i dont understand where i need to put that code, on the parent?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Or should not.

You can't do it, because iframe is a window context, in theory it should not know about its parent (even if in practice it does).

1. What should happen if you open the contents of the iframe in an independent window?
   If it's a simple action like: "I don't need this workflow", then don't use an iframe, you don't need it.
2. Are parent and iframe in the same domain? If the answer is no, you can't do it.

If you need it in any case, and they are both in the same domain, and you can't  implement it without using an iframe...

- Write the code of your dialog in the parent window `window.showDialog = function (){}`
- Call this code with `top.showDialog()` or `parent.showDialog()`

`top` in most browsers related to most parent window... 
`top` will be broken if your parent also will be shown in iframe... It's better to use `parent` instead...

Comment: thanks for help. actully i use the iframe becaue im trying to load a random content in the site. and on of those contents has a javacript dialog. if you know another way to load random content whitout using a iframe that could help me ^^

Comment: ajax? what is "random content"

Comment: that random content its basically a text area whit some input type elements and list elements. One of them has a javascript dialog. I really dont use ajax before. but if you can help me i think i can check how to use it. Thanks for your help